# Highcharts - how change JSON to csv

Tags: csv, charts, volume

I have a small problem...

```
$(function () {
$.get('../../../abc-test.csv', function(data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }

        $('#test').highcharts({

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],
            data: {
                csv: data
                //csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

abc-test.csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2013-12-20,9371.08,9413.09,9352.98,9400.18,161686900
2013-12-19,9279.68,9351.9,9257.24,9335.74,98276500
2013-12-18,9145.35,9190.73,9122.05,9181.75,82342700
2013-12-17,9142.75,9161.8,9085.12,9085.12,72207500
2013-12-16,9004.62,9187.78,8997.75,9163.56,99105600
2013-12-13,9016.78,9046.63,8990.58,9006.46,67761700
2013-12-12,9032.67,9060.54,8984.28,9017,75120200
2013-12-11,9093.26,9153.14,9065.51,9077.11,64845800
2013-12-10,9180.29,9223.73,9091.97,9114.44,74363400
```

Why this code dont't work ?
Don't work:
- Two panes, candlestick and volume
- OHLC
- 1.7 million points with async loading...

The issue is in the "date" in csv or something else ... ?